# "Let's get AppName" and "Here's AppName" now always present; used to get removed after a certain number of frequent invocations

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I've been in email contact with support and they have apparently never experienced this behavior.

I've been testing my Action for about a year now.  Recently (few weeks to a month), I've been hearing the introductory messages of "Let's get AppName" or "Here's AppName" after every single invocation.  Before this, I would only hear that message for the first few invocations after a publish of the project.  After enough frequent uses of the Action, those messages went away and all I heard was the start/end chime noises before/after my Action's responses.  Now I hear the verbal introduction every single time, which sucks! A lot!

I'm using DialogFlow with the built-in Cloud Functions for Firebase.  My Actions on Google project is in Alpha and has been this whole time.  This behavior changed on its own as I hadn't made any changes to my project anywhere near the time the behavior changed.

Here is an outline of the experience and behavior I am used to (until recently):

```
In device testing mode:

Me: Ok Google, ask AppName what the temperature is.
Google: Ok, let's get the test version of AppName.
(start action chime)
AppName: The inside temperature is 69 and the outside temperature is 32 but it feels like 25.
(end action chime)  

Using an Alpha release without device testing enabled:

Invocation #1
Me: Hey Google, tell AppName to kick-start the heat.
Google: Let's get AppName.
(start action chime)
AppName: Ok, the heat is running.  The thermostat is set to 69 and the current temperature is 68.
(end action chime)  


Invocation #2
Me: Hey Google, tell AppName to stop the heat.
Google: Here's AppName.
(start action chime)
AppName: Ok, the heat is stopping.  The thermostat is set to 69 and the current temperature is 68.
(end action chime)

(some unknown number of invocations later, though not very many, less than 12 for sure)

Invocation #???
Me: Hey Google, tell AppName to turn on PBS.
(start action chime)
AppName: Which location did you want?
Me: upstairs
AppName: Ok.
(end action chime)
```

Note the lack of Google Assistant saying anything in the last invoation.

Please tell me someone out there knows what I am talking about and can back me up on this claim of those introductory messages going away after a while.  The email support people apparently think I'm crazy.

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm primarily using Google Home smart speaker devices for assistant interaction with this Action.  Some Minis and a Hub.